# addEventListener for Radio buttons with same id

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add events using `addEventListener` to multiple radio buttons with same id ?

```
<input id="radId" type="radio" value="0" name="radioname">No
<input id="radId" type="radio" value="1" name="radioname">Yes
```

I tried to attach event using `document.getelementByID` BUT it always picks the first radio button.

Is there a way around this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As others said, an ID has to be unique. You could get elements with [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) ([note that there are some issues](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125)) and iterate over them:

```
var handler = function() {
    //...
};

var radios = document.getElementsByName('radioname');

for(var i = radios.length; i--; ) {
    radios[i].onclick = handler;
}
```

Also note that `addEventListener` does not exist in < IE8, there you have to use [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I suggest to read the [excellent articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementsByName('radioname').forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(e.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is invalid. ID must be unique.

Well, you can if you can select the elements some other way - by class, tag, childNode, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var radiobuttonlist= document.querySelectorAll('#radId');
var radioButtonItems = [].slice.call(radiobuttonlist);

    radioButtonItems.forEach(function (item, idx) {
    item.addEventListener('change',YourFunction);});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: This code can be used with different selectors ,  it is just getting the list of DOM object and looping trough them adding the change event listener

Answer (score -1):

Create array of the radio type elements and use forEach!

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="radioname">No
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radioname">Yes

<script>
//Load entire html document
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
   //Array elements radio
   var radioOption = [document.getElementsByName('radioname')[0],document.getElementsByName('radioname')[1]];
   //Use forEach
   radioOption.forEach(function(e) {
       e.addEventListener("click", function() {             
       alert(e.value);
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why creating that static array if you could do something like:
`document.getElementsByName('radioname').forEach`

Answer (score -2):

dont use the same id for 2 elemetns, use classes. and then you can use something like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("whateverclass").onclick=function()
```

Comment: This will not work as `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection.

Comment: right, i got used to using frameworks and never thought this wont work like this. thanks